# Using QGIS with system Python?

Tags: pyqgis, installation

I'm trying to use the pyrealsense library from Intel in QGIS in Win10

The current version of mine is QGIS 3.4, which comes with Python 3.7

But the pyrealsense supports pip install on 3.6 and 2.7

I tried installing QGIS2 but can't get easy_install and then get pip.

And also QGIS3 is more preferred

I tried a lot of other methods but still currently not one working found

I would like to know if there is either:

Downgrade the Python version of QGIS to python3.6

Or let QGIS console open the system Python